# Special mailbox names

Tags: email, smtp, mailbox

As far as I can see according to [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), there is only one reserved mailbox name: `postmaster`

Some time ago I saw a document containing one or two other special mailbox names (I think they were dedicated to preventing or reporting spam abuse), but can't recall where I saw it.

Are there, in fact, any other reserved or commonly used standard mailbox names besides `postmaster`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only rfc-required address is indeed `postmaster`. I recommend creating a `abuse` mailbox as well for reporting spam/hack attacks. `hostmaster` is a common address for DNS related requests.

[rfc2142](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2142) lists other commonly used mailboxes